# 'int' object has no attribute 'id' in discord.py command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have this problem for a week and I REALLY don't know how to fix this.
I'm creating a leveling system that I can add point(level) to my members by command +addpoint and then by mentioning a member in discord and then amount of point that I want to give them (as u can see in code) and also I want to save the member's point in JSON file.
I shared my code many times and I requested a solution but no one gives me a solution for this.

This is my code

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python\mclearn')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        #code
        await update_data(users, member)


    with open('user.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@client.command()
async def addpoint(ctx, user: discord.User, amountt):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        amountt = amountt.replace(" ", "")
        amountt = int(amountt)
        #code
        await update_data(users, user.id)
        await add_point(users, user.id, amountt)
        await addedpointmsg(users, user.id, message.channel)

    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention}, {str(amountt)} point daryaft kard.")

    with open('user.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


async def update_data(Users, user: discord.User):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['point'] = 0

async def add_point(Users, user, point):
    users[user.id]['point'] += point
```

and here is error that i can't fix (im begginer)

```
Ignoring exception in command addpoint:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python\mclearn\bot.py", line 165, in addpoint
    await update_data(users, user.id)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python\mclearn\bot.py", line 176, in update_data
    if not user.id in users:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I also imported every module that is needed.

Please, someone, give me a solution for this. Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend fixing your language. And read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask very very carefully if you want to understand why just sharing your code is not always enough to get good answers.

Comment: Your calling `await update_data(users, user.id)` instead of `await update_data(users, user)`

Comment: I guess await update_data(users, user.id) is right cuz user alone doesn't give anything and i want user's id to save their point in JSON.

Comment: It's completely wrong according to the function annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function annotation says that you shoud get `user` parameter in type of [User Object](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user). You got user parameter as `int` type id instead. 
Your next error can be at `user.mention`.

I propose you to double check the incoming function parameters `user` to get the expected `User Object`.